# use the toggle function to show hide a table row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I would like to use the toggle function to show hide a table row BELOW
a dynamic row, so the table would look like this

```
row from database with data
row I want to show hide (defaults to hide)
```

I know how to do this when the table is static but how do I do it when
the rows are being built based on the numbers of rows from the
database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following .

Specify a class for the row which will be created from database. Say the class is 'RowFromDB', then if you specify `$('.RowFromDB').next()` you can get the next element.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be any different if its build dynamic from .NET, you can still bind them because .NET generates the markup for you. But if its a response from an AJAX call or something you may want to look at [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method or the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Comment: and when he says "or the .live() method." he really means just look into .delegate()